# Need help for batch files renaming

Tags: bash, shell

I have a folder X with lot of files:

```
file01x01.txt
file02x01.txt
file03x01.txt
file04 01.txt
file05 01.txt
```

I would like to put a "x" between the 0401 and 0501 like the first 3 files. So far I was doing something like:

```sh
for f in *.txt ; do mv "$f" "${f// /x}" ; done
```

This works but it applies to all the `*.txt` files and I would like to avoid that. How can I do it only for `file04 01.txt` and `file05 01.txt` in my example?

I was thinking maybe something like this:

```sh
for f in file[04-05].txt ; do mv "$f" "${f// /x}" ; done
```

but I can't get the proper syntax.

Comment: `for i in  file0{4,5}*; do ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `*` wildcards plus a quoted space `' '` to find files that have a space in their name.

```
for f in file*' '*.txt; do
    mv "$f" "${f// /x}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way too:

```
find . -name "file*[[:space:]]*.txt" -exec bash -c 'f="{}"; mv "$f" "${f// /x}"' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`rename`](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/rename.1.html) tool.

if your filenames have **only** one space, this would be enough:

```
$ rename -n 's/ /x/' *txt
rename(file04 01.txt, file04x01.txt)
rename(file05 01.txt, file05x01.txt)
```

(`-n` is for "dry run", remove it to perform the actual renaming)

if your filenames have **more than one** space character, you can use something like this:

```
$ rename -n 's/ (\d*.txt)$/x$1/' *txt
rename(file04 01.txt, file04x01.txt)
rename(file05 01.txt, file05x01.txt)
rename(file with spaces 06 01.txt, file with spaces 06x01.txt)
```